# Show that $\Theta=S^1\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1])$ is homotopy equivalent to $\infty=(S^1+(1,0))\cup (S^1+(-1,0))$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

> Show that $\Theta=S^1\cup (\{0\}\times [-1,1])$ is homotopy equivalent to $\infty=(S^1+(1,0))\cup (S^1+(-1,0))$ where $(S^1 + (a, b))$ is the circle described by $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = 1$.

I can intuitively see that both are deformation retracts of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{p,q\}$. However, I am interested in finding explicit maps for these deformation retractions.

Comment: What is the meaning of addition here?

Comment: @FShrike I guess it means translation

Comment: Is $(-1, 0)$ supposed to be $(0, -1)$?

Comment: @angryavian essentially yes, but actually the $(0,1)$ will be changed to $(1,0)$. Edited the question, hope it's fine now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SayanDutta In general, it is very hard to give a formula because for example the deformation retraction from $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ to $\infty$ would require a lot of branches to ensure the continuity. The other deformation retraction (to $\Theta$) is simpler. You simply slide everything outside of the circle along the rays that emit from the origin and then you can enlarge the holes inside the circle to $\Theta$ by sliding points along the rays that emit from the removed points, so you will need three branches, all of which can be defined via straight line homotopy.

Comment: @Kevin.S I see, thanks